# How do I ungray-out the buttons in the ribbons in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, review

I want to gain full access to my Excel file. I noticed there are  some menu items in the ribbon that are grayed out. I've attached an example below.

I've tried everything in google - ungrouped all sheets, generate a new password using VBA, tried the suggestions in the Advanced Options.

Would anyone have any other suggestions? When I was in VBA, I noticed there is a password there, but it is still an unprotected document.

Grayed out buttons in Review Tab:

[image: Grayed out buttons in Review Tab]

Comment: This question belongs on [su], as it is not programming related. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works and what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: Which of these grayed out buttons do you actually need to use? Why do you think you do not already have "full access"?

Comment: Do you have entered the comment in the Workbook?

Answer (score 3):

The grayed out “delete, previous and next” comment box means there are currently no comments currently in the document. Second, the grayed out “unshare document” box means the document is not currently shared.

It appears that excel is functioning properly.